# Single-handle shower valve won't shut off

Tags: plumbing, shower

We just had a new shower valve (single handle), head, and faucet installed a couple weeks ago ("KOHLER Capilano").

It was working fine until yesterday when it would no longer shut off. What happened is as follows:

1. turn on water (normal)
2. pull the diverter up to enable shower (normal)
3. turn off water (normal...)
4. But the shower head keeps spraying cold water. (not normal!)
5. I couldn't get it to stop except by pushing the diverter back down. Then the water stopped.

I am wondering if this is a simple fix (I am handy with a screwdriver), otherwise I will have the plumber who installed it come over again to look.

Comment: Sounds like it should still be under warranty.  You might void warranty if you take it apart.  Sounds like diverter valve is jamming, getting gum up, sticking.  Might only be cleaning or replacement/debending of bent parts.

Comment: Call the plumber who installed it and describe the behavior. "Call backs" are part of their services. Don't try to fix it yourself!

Comment: This is a tub/shower, right? If you change the diverter to dump through the spigot before turning off the valve, does the water shut off properly? If so, I would consider this to be an acceptable valve. You no doubt have a pressure balancing or thermostatically balanced valve and these have their quirks.

Comment: The way I use my tub shower with diverter is to set the diverter to dump water into the tub, turn on the water to the expected temp, then step into the tub with the water still not to shower temp and pull curtain closed. Short wait till the water coming out of the spigot is warm and only then do I turn the diverter to direct water out of the shower with low flow head. We have the old double handle valves with no antiscald protection and an old gas fired tankless water heater.